# CreateFile on Mailslot fails with Error 53 ERROR_BAD_NETPATH after 2018-05 Windows 10 Feature Update 1803

Tags: windows-10, mailslot

commands such as CreateFile("\\mycomputer\mailslot\this_fails",...) fail with last error = 53 ERROR_BAD_NETPATH

That fails if used with any valid or non-existing computer name including the same computer on which the test is running.  On computers where this works, it succeeds and returns a mailslot handle even if the referenced computer does not exist or does not have a mailslot created with that name. Note that if an non-existing computer name or mailslot is used, subsequent WriteFiles on the handle will fail, but the CreateFile does succeed.

However, the CreateFile above will succeed if the Mailslot reference is explicitly local:  "\\.\mailslot\always_works"

This worked on all versions of Windows previously until the 2018-05 cumulative updates were installed.  Specifically KB4103721 (Windows 10 home) seemed to be the culprit.  [Edit: as noted in answers below, it is actually Feature Update Build 1803 that causes this issue.]

Test Client:  (works with no parameter or "." but fails with any computername).
Based on msdn [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365802(v=vs.85).aspx)

Syntax:   testclient [server computername]

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <tchar.h>

    LPTSTR SlotName = TEXT("\\\\%hs\\mailslot\\sample_mailslot");

    BOOL WriteSlot(HANDLE hSlot, LPTSTR lpszMessage)
    {
       BOOL fResult;
       DWORD cbWritten;

       fResult = WriteFile(hSlot,
         lpszMessage,
         (DWORD) (lstrlen(lpszMessage)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR),
         &cbWritten,
         (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL);

       if (!fResult)
       {
// this failure is valid if computername is not valid
          printf("WriteFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
          return FALSE;
       }

       printf("Slot written to successfully.\n");

       return TRUE;
    }

    int main(int nArgs,char * arg[])
    {
       HANDLE hFile;
       TCHAR szSlot[256];

       _stprintf (szSlot,SlotName,nArgs > 1 ? arg[1] : ".");

       _tprintf(TEXT("Writing to slot %s\n"),szSlot);
       hFile = CreateFile(szSlot,
         GENERIC_WRITE,
         FILE_SHARE_READ,
         (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL,
         OPEN_EXISTING,
         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
         (HANDLE) NULL);

       if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
       {
// this is the failure I'm trying to debug
          printf("CreateFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
          return FALSE;
       }

       WriteSlot(hFile, TEXT("Message one for mailslot."));
       WriteSlot(hFile, TEXT("Message two for mailslot."));
       Sleep(5000);
       WriteSlot(hFile, TEXT("Message three for mailslot."));
       CloseHandle(hFile);

       return TRUE;
    }
```

Test Server:  (reads a displays sent messages)
Note that duplicate messages may be received because Mailslot messages are transmitted over all possible protocols.  Based on msdn [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365785(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

HANDLE hSlot;
LPTSTR SlotName = TEXT("\\\\.\\mailslot\\sample_mailslot");

BOOL ReadSlot()
{
    DWORD cbMessage, cMessage, cbRead;
    BOOL fResult;
    LPTSTR lpszBuffer;
    TCHAR achID[80];
    DWORD cAllMessages;
    HANDLE hEvent;
    OVERLAPPED ov;

    cbMessage = cMessage = cbRead = 0;

    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("ExampleSlot"));
    if( NULL == hEvent )
        return FALSE;
    ov.Offset = 0;
    ov.OffsetHigh = 0;
    ov.hEvent = hEvent;

    fResult = GetMailslotInfo( hSlot, // mailslot handle
        (LPDWORD) NULL,               // no maximum message size
        &cbMessage,                   // size of next message
        &cMessage,                    // number of messages
        (LPDWORD) NULL);              // no read time-out

    if (!fResult)
    {
        printf("GetMailslotInfo failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (cbMessage == MAILSLOT_NO_MESSAGE)
    {
        printf("Waiting for a message...\n");
        return TRUE;
    }

    cAllMessages = cMessage;

    while (cMessage != 0)  // retrieve all messages
    {
        // Create a message-number string.

        StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR) achID,
            80,
            TEXT("\nMessage #%d of %d\n"),
            cAllMessages - cMessage + 1,
            cAllMessages);

        // Allocate memory for the message.

        lpszBuffer = (LPTSTR) GlobalAlloc(GPTR,
            lstrlen((LPTSTR) achID)*sizeof(TCHAR) + cbMessage);
        if( NULL == lpszBuffer )
            return FALSE;
        lpszBuffer[0] = '\0';

        fResult = ReadFile(hSlot,
            lpszBuffer,
            cbMessage,
            &cbRead,
            &ov);

        if (!fResult)
        {
            printf("ReadFile failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
            GlobalFree((HGLOBAL) lpszBuffer);
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Concatenate the message and the message-number string.
        StringCbCat(lpszBuffer,
                    lstrlen((LPTSTR) achID)*sizeof(TCHAR)+cbMessage,
                    (LPTSTR) achID);

        // Display the message.
        _tprintf(TEXT("Contents of the mailslot: %s\n"), lpszBuffer);

        GlobalFree((HGLOBAL) lpszBuffer);

        fResult = GetMailslotInfo(hSlot,  // mailslot handle
            (LPDWORD) NULL,               // no maximum message size
            &cbMessage,                   // size of next message
            &cMessage,                    // number of messages
            (LPDWORD) NULL);              // no read time-out

        if (!fResult)
        {
            printf("GetMailslotInfo failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hEvent);
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL WINAPI MakeSlot(LPTSTR lpszSlotName)
{
    hSlot = CreateMailslot(lpszSlotName,
        0,                             // no maximum message size
        MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER,         // no time-out for operations
        (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL); // default security

    if (hSlot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateMailslot failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void main()
{
   MakeSlot(SlotName);

   while(TRUE)
   {
      ReadSlot();
      Sleep(3000);
   }
}
```

The test server to read messages, and the test client to send messages can be run in different cmd shells on the same computer, or run on different computers.  When it fails, it fails immediately and seems to be a problem trying to resolve the network path name. On the same computer, file shares such as \\ThisComputer\share work properly from the same computer or a different one.

NetBIOS is enabled over TCP/IP for the network adapters in use. The network adapters are designated as Private. Firewall was disabled for testing.  File and Printer sharing are enabled.  Computers are in same workgroup. Computer name resolution works, and this fails even if IP addresses are used (even 127.0.0.1).

Comment: Win10 agile bugs are proportional to how often a feature gets used.  And nobody uses mailslots.  Microsoft Support is your best bet to get ahead.  Five hundred bucks to start talking, but surely you'll get that back.

Comment: something else I noticed, you can still open and broadcast on mailslots. So "\\\*\mailslot\slotname" can be opened and does work even in Windows v1803.  As noted before "\\.\mailslot\slotname" also works. Single-character computer names do not work though only . and * work.  

The ability to broadcast is one of the advantages of mailslots, so it is helpful that those still work.  For my app, I re-routed non-broadcast messages through a socket and was able to keep sending broadcast messages via mailslot. Hacky but effective to get our software working for now.

Comment: I asked Microsoft and the contact confirmed this issue. Here is no ETA for a fix. Roll back to 1709 and delay feature updates in WU options in Settings app or in WSUS.

Comment: I got the reply that this is [already fixed for some time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55246483/1466046)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is already fixed since last Year

[September 26, 2018—KB4458469 (OS Build 17134.320)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4458469/windows-10-update-kb4458469)

> Addresses an issue that causes NTLTEST, DCLOCATOR, or joining an
>   Active Directory and SAMBA domain to fail when using the NetBIOS
>   domain name. The error is “An Active Directory domain Controller (AD
>   DC) for the domain %domain% could not be contacted”. **This also
>   addresses connection issues for applications that use mailslots to
>   communicate.**

Comment: It does seem to work again. Broken May-2018. Fixed by Sept-2018.  I hadn't noticed bc I had to deploy a workaround in May-2018.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with the latest Feature Update from Windows 10 (1803), not a patch via Windows Update.
Please check if you are using build 17134.48 (Also known as 1803)

Try a downgrade to 1709.

01/09/2019:
With the latests 1809 Build Mailslots are working again

Comment: I confirmed that it's Windows 10 build 1803 that exhibits this problem in Windows 10 Pro or Home.  Build 1709 works.  Unfortunately, since that is a major Feature Update, it removes all previous restore points.  I can restore from a backup of the computer, but I'm trying to help users of software that uses mailslots, and not many will have a recent backup.

I'm looking for a required service or protocol that has been disabled, but I don't see anything that is different. I wonder if Microsoft no longer allows mailslot communications to other computers.

Answer (score 0):

I didn`t find any information that mailslot communication is not longer supported in that way you do this. 
I think it is a bug. 
But the only way to find out is to open a support ticket via support.microsoft.com.

Or you could post here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums

Until we get any new information from Microsoft everybody who needs mailslots should block  the feature upgrade 1803.

Comment: while this may be useful, it's better to post this as a comment. this does not qualify as an answer

Comment: it may be a new bug in name validation of CreateFile since mailslots can still be created and receive messages from computers still running older versions/builds of Windows.